# Can't add new HTML elements on a website with a content script

Tags: javascript, html, web, browser-extension

So, I've been trying to make a web extension that would help integrate my app better with a website, but I'm stuck at the injecting a new `a` tag. The website I'm trying to integrate is https://modrinth.com/(mod or resourcepack or shader)/foo

src/onMod.js

```js
const main = () => {
  let inputGroup = document.getElementsByClassName("input-group")[0];
  let mcmodpackmanagerbutton = document.createElement("a");

  let slug = "sodium"; // Place holder

  slug = window.location.href.split("/")[4]; // This thing doesn't change

  mcmodpackmanagerbutton.href = "mcmodpackmanager://modrinthopen?id=" + slug;
  mcmodpackmanagerbutton.className = "iconified-button";
  mcmodpackmanagerbutton.innerHTML = "Open with Minecraft Modpack Manager";
  mcmodpackmanagerbutton.setAttribute("rel", "noopener nofollow"); // Other links on modrinth.com use this

  console.log("SLUG: " + slug);

  inputGroup.appendChild(mcmodpackmanagerbutton);
};

main();
```

I've been expecting something like this: https://i.imgur.com/UdkQ5ZM.png,
but instead the button comes for a second and then disappears

Comment: Can you check if it is still in the DOM after it disappears. If so there must be a style for **a** tag. If it is not in DOM you are triggering a render on the website you are trying to inject.

Answer (score 0):

Much like React, Vue. js utilizes a Virtual DOM which is a representation or a copy of the actual DOM; it's also known as a “shadow DOM” and is rendered using JavaScript.

However, should a value change or whatever other trigger, the element html might get overwritten by the actual Virtual DOM content.

I can only think of a patchy way to get around this and use a `MutationObserver` to detect changes in a parent element and immediately re-add the button. It might not even flicker.

```js
// select the element to observe
const targetElement = document.querySelector('#target-element');

// create a button element
const button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = 'button one - revived';

// create a mutation observer instance
const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
  if (!targetElement.querySelector("button")) {
    targetElement.appendChild(button);
  }
});

// configure the observer to watch for child node removals
const config = {
  childList: true
};

// start observing the target element for changes
observer.observe(targetElement, config);
```

```html
<div id="target-element" style="padding:20px">
  <button>button one</button>
</div>

<button onclick="document.querySelector('#target-element button').remove();">remove button 1</button>
```